# Use of 'laugh' in 'be laughed out of the building'

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, passive-voice

I encountered the following sentence, but I'm curious about the use of 'be laughed out of'.

> If you had gone to her court in 1850 and suggested that this empire would be over within a generation, you would have **been laughed out of** the building.

I searched and found [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/laugh+someone+out+of):

- laugh someone out of something -- to force someone to leave a place by laughing in ridicule. *The citizens laughed the speaker out of the hall. We laughed the city council out of the auditorium*.

According to that, I could rewrite the sentence and change the voice from passive and active. Like this:

> they would have **laughed you out of** the building.

Is it correct that that would have had the meaning of 'you would have been laughed out of the building'?

Comment: What are you actually asking? You seem to have already provided the meaning. The latter part of your question seems to imply that you're asking if you should use the passive or active voice. (Both are fine; it's a matter of style.)

Comment: Although I found the meaning, I need to confirm if the meaning is right in that sentence. Thank you for your reply.